# Main Activity opens again even already opened when clicked on notification generated by service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, notifications

In main activity I'm loading fragment and on click of an item of fragment new playing activity with playing music is launched along with service and notification is generated. On click of notification I'm sending intent to main Activity. The problem I'm facing is that when I'm on playing activity and click to notification main activity is launched over existing playing activity and overlaps it. I wants to to notify user if app is already in stack otherwise launch main activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:launchMode="singleTop"` flag to the activity in the mainfiest file, so that it makes sure the current activity instance is opened instead of launching a new one.

```
<manifest
     <application
        <activity
            android:name="....MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

UPDATE:

As you've two different activities, and the current activity is different than the one launched by the notification, then use the `singleTask` or `singleInstance` flags.. Check the documentation table [in here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element).

Comment: I did the same but issue is that when I click on item new activity is launched and main activity goes to pause state. During pause state when I click to notification main Activity is launched over that playing activity

Comment: Issue is resolved by adding launchmode to singleTask

Comment: @MuhammadSajid Right as you've two different activities in your case

Comment: @MuhammadSajid I guess also `singleInstance` can be worked in your case